# Update ordered list when array changes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-binding, observer-pattern, publish-subscribe

So I've used Backbone and Angular quite a bit and gotten used to data binding / view updating within those ecosystems, but I don't know how I would achieve this in plain JS (no frameworks/libraries).

Right now I have a simple `UserList`, and I would like to watch for changes to it and trigger and update of an unordered list when it happens.

```
var ContactList = {
    list: [],
    push: function(obj) {
        this.storage.push(obj);
    },
    remove: functon(obj) {
        return this.storage.splice(this.storage.indexOf(obj), 1);
    }
};

var Contact = function(attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes || {};
};

Contact.prototype.get = function(property) {
    return this.attributes[property];
};

Contact.prototype.set = function(property, value) {
    this.attributes[property] = value;
};
```

Ideally the following would automatically add to a list.  I could just add a callback to the push and remove methods, but that seems like it doesn't scale very well if I get to a point where I'm adding more methods to operate on my list.  I've been reading a bit about the observer pattern, but not sure if that's really what I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to pass the callback to every call of ContactList.push and ContactList.remove and all the ContactList methods you are yet to write. Instead, the ContactList will know when he has changed and then announce that fact to the world. In a simple implementation, ContactList could have his own onChange method which he could call:

```
var ContactList = {
    list: [],
    push: function (obj) {
        this.list.push(obj);
        this.onChange();
    },
    remove: function (obj) {
        var index = this.list.indexOf(obj);
        if (index > -1) {
            var removed = this.list.splice(index, 1);
            this.onChange();
            return removed;
        } else {
            return null;   
        }
    }
};
```

You would then, obviously, have to define ConactList.onChange:

```
ContactList.onChange =  function () {
    console.log(this.list);
    /* update your ul element */
};
```

This solution will not allow you to add subscribers dynamically to Contact List's change event, but it might be a helpful starting point.